# How can I display the responsive datatable's expand/collapse icon in the right side of the first column's value?

Tags: javascript, css, datatable, datatables

I'm using responsive datatable (https://www.datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/classes.html). but the expand/collapse icon is appearing in the left side of the first column's value.

How can I change that to appear in the right side of first column's value.

Also want to change the icon style to use Font Awesome's icon

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   0
        } ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
  });
} );
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display responsive" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a simple code example that duplicates the issue you are experiencing.

Comment: Where's your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a css Selector

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td:first-child:before, 
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th:first-child:before
```

which defines the position of the element.

In your css overwrite it:

```
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>td:first-child:before, 
table.dataTable.dtr-inline.collapsed>tbody>tr>th:first-child:before  {
left: auto;
right: 4px;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Move the blank `<th></th>` to the last column and update the target value to the last as well.

```js
 $(document).ready( function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: {
            details: {
                type: 'column'
            }
        },
        columnDefs: [ {
            className: 'control',
            orderable: false,
            targets:   5
        } ],
        order: [ 1, 'asc' ]
  });
} );
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>       
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <table id="example" class="display responsive" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </tfoot>

        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$3,120</td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>`
```